# Rotate doesn't work with BarChart and BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: graphics

```
Rotate@BarChart[RandomReal[1, {4, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

Even though the FullForm generated by BarChart is Graphics expression, Rotate has no effect on BarChart and many other packaged plot functions. However, it's frequently necessary to rotate, scale and align such plots to other graphics in composite data visualizations (eg, imagine a heatmap augmented with row and column descriptive statistics visualized with two corresponding BoxWhiskerChart)

How can rotatable, translatable, etc. graphics be extracted from functions like BarChart and BoxWhiskerChart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You left off the angle to rotate through:

```
Rotate[BarChart[RandomReal[1, {4, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Percentile"], 90 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Rotate[BarChart[RandomReal[1, {4, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Percentile"], 45 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Strange that it didn't throw an error, though.

Comment: Indeed, it should give an error message.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you @F'x, Eli. I'm so used to GraphicConverter and other apps that have default 90 deg Rotate.

Comment: @jens In cases where the inputs do not match the defined formats Mathematica just returns the function unevaluated. This is by design.

Comment: @SjoerdC Not really. Try `Map[x]` where you see the red pointer because of the wrong format, and you get a message `::argtu:` The same holds here with `Rotate[x]` (you get a red pointer to warn you, but no message).

Comment: @jens The OP used the function in prefix format. In that case there is no possibility for syntax coloring. I guess many functions have a reasonable output built-in given insufficient parameters . Take RotateLeft[{x}] for instance. Same for Rotate[x]. Simple user-defined functions return unevaluated if the argument patterns don't match the definition.

Comment: @Sjoerd but then the output for the OP would have been `Rotate[`--Graphics--`]`. Instead it was just the graphics.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Also, try `Plot@x` which throws an error and outputs `Plot[x]`

Comment: I only said that the prefix form doesn't give you syntax coloring.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `Rotate` you could use the `BarOrigin` option to `BarChart` to change the orientation.  In this case the graphic is still wider than it is tall:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {4, 5}],
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brett. These features and options (eg "Percentile") are barely mentioned in Documentation. If only Wolfram would link MMA.SE to help.